# Python comparing if indexes differs from one

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I'm new to Python and I need to create a code which deletes the biggest negative numbers ONLY when their indexes differs from each other for mor than one, e.g. if I have an array of values like [-3, -1, -2, -5] and their indexes in original array are [0, 3, 4, 5] I have to delete value -5 with index 5 as it is the smallest and then delete -3 with index 0 as it is second smallest, and then I delete -1 with index 3. That are all values that can be deleted because other indexes aren't differing from each other for more than one eg. 4-3=1, 5-4=1.

I created the below code, but getting error IndexError: list index out of range. How can I solve it?

```
for j in range(len(negative_ratings_id)):
        if negative_ratings_id[j] == negative_ratings_id[j+1] + 1 or negative_ratings_id[j] == negative_ratings_id[j+1] - 1:
            negative_ratings_val.pop(j)
print(negative_ratings_id)
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
Your posted code is incomplete, you haven't given the full error message, and you have not tried to trace the problem values,

Comment: Is there any way to compare indexes in a better way than I did in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
for j in range(len(negative_ratings_id)):
```

to

```
for j in range(len(negative_ratings_id)-2):
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped!